# PC: C server application / Android: Java client application - connecting client/server applications which are not on the same network

Tags: c, network-programming

I am developing a C application which will run on my computer (connected on a local router) to act as a server while allowing any device from the Internet to connect to it.

Also, I am developing an Android APK in Java which will be a client (using mobile data, for example), but this is not currently of relevance.

What I would like to do is for my C application to hold some data which can only be accessed via the client on the request. When user installs the APK on Android phone, login credentials are required and after that he/she has complete access to the server application and can get the necessary data or send the instructions to the server.

So far I have only programmed TCP/IP over LAN. I am interested in how can I create a C application that will live "online" not only "locally" as I would like to access it from different sources, not only LAN users.

Can anybody help with this and explain me what should I do? I am trying to avoid any libraries (if possible) because I'd like to learn more about Network programming.

Comment: If you use standard sockets and TCP/IP, then there's no difference between a local network or the whole Internet. All you need is a publicly available address where the clients can connect, and you're set to go.

Comment: Does it mean I need to find an online server which will provide the public IP or is there a free workaround?

Comment: If the server should be locate in a LAN which is connected to internet using NAT, the gateway (modem, router?) might provide port forwarding, which if configured appropriately allows you to from the internet connect to the gateway on a specific port. The gateway then connects to the server inside the LAN and proxies the connection.

Comment: @alk do you maybe have some guide on how to do that?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Java, C and software engineering. Question is "how do I make my home server accessible to the internet?". There are multiple tutorials about setting up home servers (i.e. **configuration of port forwarding on home routers**). You can ask some specific questions about configuration of routers at https://superuser.com/